# Where to put the code conventions rules?

Tags: java, android, coding-style

I am working on a Project (Android Project) with a group of developers (reside in the same location).

We need to put some rules to naming classes, files, xml elements, etc ...

Currently we have a file at the root of the project named "code_conventions.txt" that we write the rules in a free text way.

ex:
`1. Append "Activity" string after each class in the app that extends Activity Class`

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: whatever way people will adhere to...

Comment: I just asking about if there's a standard way

Answer (score 2):

The company I work at has a set of coding standards it uses for all Java development. The file is hosted on our own wiki intranet. New users have to read the file and follow the conventions set. The file contains conventions like prefixing member variable name with `m`, eg. `mUsername`, or using [camel case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) for Class and Method names.

Comment: We used a `wiki` for this as well, and it works very nicely - as it's easy for anyone to edit, and provides source control, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Those kind of rules are ripe for automation.  Check out [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) which will automatically check enforcement of these types of rules as you code so no manual checks need to be carried out.

You could, for example, use the regular expression checks to verify the assertion you have noted in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to enforce coding conventions you can look at using http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/ and making that part of your build.